# Tizen Studio Emulator has undefined webapis.js

Tags: webapi, privileges, tizen, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I am running Tizen Studio 5.1 with the latest emulator 7.0. I am using a hosted web application method (can provide more info if needed). When debugging I get this error:

```
webapis.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: widget is not defined
    at webapis.js:1
    at webapis.js:1
```

so I click on the line item error to get here...

```
 var downloadedwebapis = **widget**.getDownloadedWebapis();
```

I don't know what widget is, and I am new to tizen but based on research, it feels like I need to add a privilege on the config, or maybe add a script tag somewhere...any thoughts? ...Also in my app I set the script: '$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js'.

Comment: I don'r really understand, but as a workaround I can debug using an actual tv.